# ReactNative Expo Webpack: add "plugins" and "resolve" parameters occur exception: throw new Error('Callback was already called.');

Tags: react-native, npm, webpack, expo

I'm trying to install react-web-config package in expo react-native application by this instruction:
https://github.com/tanhauhau/react-web-config

At first I'm create webpack config by this instruction:
https://docs.expo.io/guides/customizing-webpack/

Got the following config:

```
const createExpoWebpackConfigAsync = require("@expo/webpack-config");

module.exports = async function (env, argv) {
  const config = await createExpoWebpackConfigAsync(
      {
        ...env,
        // Passing true will enable the default Workbox + Expo SW configuration.
        offline: true,
      },
      argv
  );
  // Customize the config before returning it.
  return config;
};
```

Checking by:

> expo build:web
>
> ┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
> │
> │ │   There is a new version of expo-cli available (3.28.1).
> │ │   You are currently using expo-cli 3.27.12
> │ │   Install expo-cli globally using the package manager of your
> choice;   │ │   for example: `npm install -g expo-cli` to get the
> latest version      │ │
> │
> └─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
>
> √ Expo Webpack   Compiled successfully in 1.82s
>
> web  Compiled successfully.
>
> web  Offline (PWA) support is not enabled in this build. Learn more
> https://expo.fyi/enabling-web-service-workers

That's ok.

Now returning to instruction:
https://github.com/tanhauhau/react-web-config
Got new config:

```
const createExpoWebpackConfigAsync = require("@expo/webpack-config");
const ReactWebConfig = require('react-web-config/lib/ReactWebConfig').ReactWebConfig;
const path = require('path');
const envFilePath = path.resolve(__dirname, '.env');

module.exports = async function (env, argv) {

  const config = await createExpoWebpackConfigAsync(
      {
        ...env,
        offline: true,         // Passing true will enable the default Workbox + Expo SW configuration.
      },
      argv
  );
  config.plugins.push(ReactWebConfig(envFilePath));
  
  config.resolve.alias['react-native-config'] = 'react-web-config';

  // Customize the config before returning it.
  return config;
};
```

Checking:

> expo build:web

Get an error:

> - Expo Webpack █████████████████████████ building (10%) 5/6 modules 1 active  node_modules@babel\runtime\helpers\classCallCheck.js
>
> (node:7972) DeprecationWarning: Tapable.plugin is deprecated. Use new
> API on `.hooks` instead (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show
> where the warning was created)
>
> C:\Users\kxxo\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:16
> throw new Error('Callback was already called.');
> ^ Error: Callback was already called.
> at throwError (C:\Users\kxxo\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:16:11)
> at C:\Users\kxxo\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:2818:7
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)

I think problem is in this two new lines:

> config.plugins.push(ReactWebConfig(envFilePath));
>
> config.resolve.alias['react-native-config'] = 'react-web-config';

If I'm comment first or second line, build will successfully compiled (but of course app in this case will not work properly)

Comment: Did you work this out? I've just found the same problem.

Comment: @marky Unfortunately no. The last ideas were to rebuild the config for the webpack myself. Or maybe use alternative libraries. But I was having so many other problems with the expo that I decided to switch to another activity.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks. I ended up basically just taking the code from ReactWebConfig() and putting it directly in my webpack config. Works fine now. Not sure why it wouldn’t just work as-is though!